# Tablix resizes on screen render

Tags: reporting-services, resize, rendering, ssrs-tablix

I'm working with SSRS and i've made a report that contains several tablix objects pointing to different datasets and place aligned on screen due to they have the same size columns and rows. When rendering in Chrome some cells of some tablixs shrink and i get a mess in the alignment matter. The properties of can shrink and can grow are in false option. Any suggestion to solve this out?
Thanks in advance!

I need the tablixs maintain the alignment to make users read in a right way the info shown. In visual studio the render is ok, the problem appears on browsers rendering.